# abbreviations and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Basically, the function has to prompt the user to enter the first two letters of a day of the week and it should return the full worded day of the week. It should continue to prompt the user to do this until the user inputs an invalid two characters.

```
def abr():
    abr = input("Enter a day abbreviation:")
    days = {Su: Sunday, Mo: Monday, Tu: Tuesday, We:Wenesday, Th: Thursday, Fr: Friday, Sa: Saturday, Su: Sunday}
    if days in abr:
        return days['']
```

I tried to address this using a dictionary but i'm not too familiar with dictionaries and what their limits are.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: See [http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), it is the documentation of the `dict` type and has information about the operators and methods which a `dict` has.

Answer (score 3):

**kojiro** is right. You must reverse you condition for

```
if abr in days:
    return days[abr]
```

Do not forget to use string for your dictionary keys and values since the user input will be returned as a string which you will use as the key.

You must also use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) since [`input` is actually equivalent to an eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) which would require your user to input "Tu" instead of Tu.

As for the loop, you can use a while loop and exit when you detect an invalid abreviation

```
def abr():
    abr = raw_input("Enter a day abbreviation:")
    days = {"Su": "Sunday", 
            "Mo": "Monday", 
            "Tu": "Tuesday", 
            "We": "Wednesday", 
            "Th": "Thursday", 
            "Fr": "Friday", 
            "Sa": "Saturday", 
            "Su": "Sunday"}
    if abr in days:
        return days[abr]
    return None


while(1):
    day = abr()
    if day is not None:
        print day
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Good call on the raw_input().

Answer (score 2):

You weren't too far off, you just got the order reversed. Oh, and those dictionary keys and values should both be strings.

```
def abr():
    """Return the day given a two-letter abbreviation."""
    # Don't use the function name as a variable in the function.
    # It's just not good practice.
    abbrev = input("Enter a day abbreviation:") 
    days = {
        "Su": "Sunday",
        "Mo": "Monday",
        "Tu": "Tuesday",
        "We": "Wednesday", # [Spelling fixed]
        "Th": "Thursday",
        "Fr": "Friday",
        "Sa": "Saturday",
    } # Extra Sunday removed

    return days.get(abbrev, '')
```

To make the loop behavior happen so it keeps going until they hit an invalid abbreviation, call the function in a loop:

```
while True:
    if abr() == "":
        break
```

or a bit shorter:

```
while abr() != "":
    pass
```

Comment: It's not working. :/ Also, another thing that needs to be addressed is how I make my code prompt the user continuously until an invalid abbreviation is entered.

Comment: @97834657647563 – it works fine, but there're a lot of questions you're not asking, like "How come it doesn't print the days out?" :P

Answer (score 0):

current_designation_upper = Transformed_Data.designation.tolist()[i].upper()
        current_designation_upper_array = re.split("[ -.!@#$%^&*()_+=~`:<>,/'|}{[]|]", current_designation_upper)
        role_current_designation_null_removed = [x for x in current_designation_upper_array if x]
        current_designation_upper_array_with_abbrevation = ''
        for k in range(0, len(role_current_designation_null_removed)):
            temp_current_designation_upper_array_with_abbrevation = current_designation_upper_array_with_abbrevation + role_current_designation_null_removed[k][0]